# Obtaining correct boundary conditions around a pole for Bessel equation plus delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, singular-solution

Consider the following Bessel-like equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \rho^2}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \rho}+u=\frac{A}{\rho}\delta(\rho)
$$
Here, $\rho$ is non negative. This equation actually came from studying a particular problem in cylindrical coordinates, so that's the reasoning behind this requirement. What I have trouble figuring out (not just here but in general) is what the general method for obtaining the correct condition for the solutions at 0. I know one way is to write $u$ as a linear combination of Bessel functions etc and figure out the coefficients. But I know there is a different way, which has to do with integrating the equation, and is more general, since it also applies to other ODEs.

I tried to just integrate both sides and take a limit, but I don't know how I am supposed to integrate the delta function since $\rho$ has to be non negative.

Of course I am aware the delta is no function etc, but I'm not sure how to treat this specific problem distributionally either. I've seen that the solution is supposed to be something like:
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial\rho} = A $$
But I'm not sure how to obtain that here.

I've been stuck on similar problems before, which is why I would appreciate some general help and possibly some resource recommendations on how to better treat these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, inasmuch as the object $\frac{\delta(\rho)}{\rho}$ is not a defined distribution, the ODE

$$\frac{d^2u}{d\rho^2}+\frac1\rho\frac{du}{d\rho}+u=\frac{A}{\rho}\delta(\rho)\tag1$$

is also not defined.  However, we can interpret the ODE in $(1)$ to mean that in distribution

$$\begin{align}
\rho\frac{d^2u}{d\rho^2}+\frac{du}{d\rho}+\rho u&=\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\rho \frac{du}{d\rho}\right)+u\\\\
&=A\delta(\rho)\tag2
\end{align}$$

Next, let's move the singularity away from the origin and write

$$\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\rho \frac{df}{d\rho}\right)+f=A\delta(\rho-\rho')\tag 3$$

Solution to $(3)$ is given by

$$f(\rho)=\begin{cases}BJ_0(\rho)&,\rho<\rho'\\\\CJ_0(\rho)+DY_0(\rho)&,\rho>\rho'
\end{cases}$$

Enforcing continuity at $\rho=\rho'$ we must have

$$\begin{align}
(B-C)J_0(\rho')=DY_0(\rho')
\end{align}\tag4$$

And from $(3)$, we see that

$$\rho'\left((C-B)J_0'(\rho')+DY_0'(\rho')\right)=A \tag5$$

Solving $(4)$ and $(5)$ simultaneously, and using the Wronsian

$$J_0(x)Y_0'(x)-J_0'(x)Y_0(x)=\frac2{\pi x}$$

we find that

$$D=\frac{A\pi}{2}J_0(\rho')$$

Finally, letting $\rho'\to 0^+$, we find that

$$u(\rho)=BJ_0(\rho)+\frac{A\pi}{2}Y_0(\rho)$$

Comment: I see, the main point I missed was moving the singularity away from the origin. Thanks!

Comment: However, one thing I don't know is how I can do that without assuming the solution in terms of Bessel functions. I know there is some trick where you can somehow integrate both sides and get a condition. But I couldn't really do it.

Comment: Well, that is how Equation $(5)$ was obtained.  "Integrate" both sides from $\rho'-\varepsilon$ to $\rho'+\varepsilon$ where $\rho'>\varepsilon>0$, enforce continuity of $f(\rho)$ at $\rho'$, and let $\varepsilon\to 0^+$.

Comment: Right, I see. I forgot to enforce continuity and I couldn't see how to proceed since I didn't know how to get rid of the integral of the second term on the left hand side. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndreasChristophilopoulos You're quite welcome.  My pleasure!